# Why is Google Colab working slower on GPU than my pc on CPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I created encoder-deocder model for translation purposes. The issue is that training such model on my CPU takes less time than training it using free GPU in Google Colab (at least this is what Colab tells me). 
What causes such behaviour? Since I think it is literally impossible that training with CPU is faster than with GPU. I double checked and my notebook is set to be using GPU, My Jupyter notebook uses the same version of keras and tf as Google Colab and both scripts are identical. Training one epoch on Colab takes over 21 hours, on my CPU less than 2 hours. My guess is that it would be caused by memory allocation but I relly don't know. 
Below merged code from notebook. Some of the values are hardcoded so you can see sizes of specific vectors/matrices.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense
from keras.utils import plot_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class Language:
    def __init__(self, lang, counter, is_target, threshold):
        self.lang = lang
        self.counter = counter
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.word_to_index = {'<unk>':1}
        self.index_to_word = {'<unk>':1}
        self.num_words = 1
        if is_target:
            self.word_to_index.update({'<START>':2, '<STOP>':3})
            self.index_to_word.update({2:'<START>', 3:'<STOP>'})
            self.num_words += 2

    def add_word(self, word):
        if word not in self.word_to_index.keys():
            if self.counter[word] > self.threshold:
                self.word_to_index[word] = self.num_words+1
                self.index_to_word[self.num_words+1] = word
                self.num_words += 1

    def add_sentence_from_string(self, sent):
        for word in sent.split(' '):
            self.add_word(word)
            
    def add_sentence_from_list(self, sent):
        for word in sent:
            self.add_word(word)

en_sents = []
fr_sents = []

with open('Data/fra.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        en, fr = line.split('\t')[:2]
        en_sents.append(en.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8"))
        fr_sents.append(fr.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8"))

def clean_dataset(sents, is_target, counter):
    def count_words(words, counter):
        for word in words:
            try:
                counter[word] += 1
            except KeyError:
                counter[word] = 1
            
    clean = []
    for s in sents:
        s = "".join(l.lower() for l in s if l not in string.punctuation)
        if is_target:
            words =  ['<START>'] + " ".join(s.split()).split(' ') + ['<STOP>']
            count_words(words, counter)
        else:
            words = " ".join(s.split()).split(' ')
            count_words(words, counter)
        clean.append(words)
    return clean

en_word_counter = {}
fr_word_counter = {}

fr_clean = clean_dataset(fr_sents, True, fr_word_counter)
en_clean = clean_dataset(en_sents, False, en_word_counter)

en_lang = Language('en', en_word_counter, False, 5) # num_words 5663
fr_lang = Language('fr', fr_word_counter, False, 5) # num_words 8634

for en, fr in zip(en_clean, fr_clean):
    en_lang.add_sentence_from_list(en)
    fr_lang.add_sentence_from_list(fr)

max_input_len = 0
max_output_len = 0

for en in en_clean:
    if len(en) > max_input_len:
        max_input_len = len(en)
    
for fr in fr_clean:
    if len(fr) > max_output_len:
        max_output_len = len(fr)
    
def tokenize_sentences(sents, language):
    tokenized = []
    for sent in sents:
        encoded = []
        for word in sent:
            try: 
                w = language.word_to_index[word]
            except KeyError:
                w = 1
            encoded.append(w)
        tokenized.append(encoded)
    return tokenized

input_data =  np.array(tokenize_sentences(en_clean, en_lang))
output_data = np.array(tokenize_sentences(fr_clean, fr_lang))

def pad_sequences(sents, max_len):
    for sent in sents:
        size = max_len - len(sent)
        sent += [0]*size

pad_sequences(input_data, max_input_len)
pad_sequences(output_data, max_output_len)

# Encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,), name='encoder_input')
encoder_embedding = Embedding(en_lang.num_words, 64, mask_zero=True, name='encoder_embedding')(encoder_inputs)
# lstm_1 = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, name='encoder_lstm_1')(encoder_embedding)
lstm_2 = LSTM(64, return_state=True, name='encoder_lstm_2')
_, state_h, state_c = lstm_2(encoder_embedding)

# Decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,), name='decoder_input')
decoder_embedding = Embedding(fr_lang.num_words+1, 64, mask_zero=True, name='decoder_embedding'(decoder_inputs)
# lstm_3 = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, name='decoder_lstm_1')(decoder_embedding, initial_state=       [state_h, state_c])
lstm_4 = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, name='decoder_lstm_2')(decoder_embedding, initial_state=   [state_h, state_c])
output = Dense(8633+1, activation='softmax', name='output')(lstm_4)

model = Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

xtrain, xtext, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(input_data, output_data, train_size=0.9)

def batch_generator(xdata, ydata, batch_size=128, max_input_len=44, max_output_len=56,    vocab_size=8633+1):
    while True:   
        for i in range(0, len(xdata), batch_size):
            encoder_inputs = np.zeros((batch_size, max_input_len), dtype='float32')
            decoder_inputs = np.zeros((batch_size, max_output_len), dtype='float32')
            decoder_outputs = np.zeros((batch_size, max_output_len, vocab_size), dtype='float32')

            for j, (input_data, target_data) in enumerate(zip(xdata[i:i+batch_size], ydata[i:i+batch_size])):
                encoder_inputs[j] = input_data
                decoder_inputs[j] = target_data

                for k, word_index in enumerate(target_data):
                    if word_index != 0:
                        decoder_outputs[j, k, word_index] = 1
        yield ((encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs), decoder_outputs)

gen = batch_generator(xtrain, ytrain)

class CustomCallback(Callback):
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        model.save(f'gdrive/My Drive/Colab/Models/model-{epoch}.h5')
    
callback = CustomCallback()

model.fit(gen, 
          epochs=10, 
          callbacks=[callback],
          steps_per_epoch=len(xtrain)//128)
```

Output of ! nvidia-smi
[image]

Comment: What is the output of `!nvidia-sm`?

Comment: @yudhiesh posted output below code

Comment: So you are in fact using the GPU. Could you try retraining to see that it wasn't a one-off thing?

Comment: I tried several times and the result was the same. I recently read that this may be due to generator function so I will try to figure out why

Comment: I don't see how a generator could be the problem. It would actually help reduce the memory usage. Where is the data located?

Comment: It is loaded from my Google Drive, I forgot to mention this

Comment: Maybe the problem actually lies within generator function. On my personal CPU single yield takes ~5 secs. CPU on Google Colab is way slower than this. Seems like the only option is to optimize the generator.